# Find The Intersections of Lines and Create Seperate Lines

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, intersection, cad

I have got a list of an axes list of an AutoCad Drawing. Something Like:

```
[Line3D(Point3D(1647113117371448512892615841780535357281063/737059219536588389452555455100000000000,
                1366943276273750947371820063466288403112033/737059219536588389452555455100000000000,0),
        Point3D(26100284670260312636891118431/12305005361967700000000000,
                1189236919681/781250000, 0)), ...]
```

When I try to plot them, lines that should be distinct are plotting as the same line. So instead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Id4.png) I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G68mZ.png). Here are some example lines:

```
[Line3D(Point3D(1647113117371448512892615841780535357281063/737059219536588389452555455100000000000,
                1366943276273750947371820063466288403112033/737059219536588389452555455100000000000, 0),
        Point3D(26100284670260312636891118431/12305005361967700000000000,1189236919681/781250000, 0)),
 Line3D(Point3D(26100284670260312636891118431/12305005361967700000000000, 1189236919681/781250000, 0),
        Point3D(25165031213118241584901717751/12305005361967700000000000, 32496091107827/25000000000, 0)),
 Line3D(Point3D(41101789294162424289223442852282888370853/12972516184739051605249750292000000000,
                6691132495400952526204407114066106055714449/3567441950803239191443681330300000000000, 0),
        Point3D(1428208758971484993356170173/478363263194784800000000, 1189236919681/781250000, 0)),
 Line3D(Point3D(1428208758971484993356170173/478363263194784800000000, 1189236919681/781250000, 0),
        Point3D(6865969238483742249815501841/2391816315973924000000000, 32496091107827/25000000000, 0)),
 Line3D(Point3D(1647113117371448512892615841780535357281063/737059219536588389452555455100000000000,
                1366943276273750947371820063466288403112033/737059219536588389452555455100000000000, 0),
        Point3D(41101789294162424289223442852282888370853/12972516184739051605249750292000000000,
                6691132495400952526204407114066106055714449/3567441950803239191443681330300000000000, 0)),
 Line3D(Point3D(41101789294162424289223442852282888370853/12972516184739051605249750292000000000,
                6691132495400952526204407114066106055714449/3567441950803239191443681330300000000000, 0),
        Point3D(42856219552476685009520165509926367369987/21754044541659661721907121840000000000,
                1105918704715895215440142199637240956944223/598236224895640697352445850600000000000, 0)),
 Line3D(Point3D(26100284670260312636891118431/12305005361967700000000000, 1189236919681/781250000, 0),
        Point3D(1428208758971484993356170173/478363263194784800000000, 1189236919681/781250000, 0)),
 Line3D(Point3D(1428208758971484993356170173/478363263194784800000000, 1189236919681/781250000, 0),
        Point3D(3662923296227402176907170887/2001416543837740000000000, 1189236919681/781250000, 0)),
 Line3D(Point3D(25165031213118241584901717751/12305005361967700000000000, 32496091107827/25000000000, 0),
        Point3D(6865969238483742249815501841/2391816315973924000000000, 32496091107827/25000000000, 0)),
 Line3D(Point3D(6865969238483742249815501841/2391816315973924000000000, 32496091107827/25000000000, 0),
        Point3D(3472204942560698802701958357/2001416543837740000000000, 32496091107827/25000000000, 0)),
 Line3D(Point3D(42856219552476685009520165509926367369987/21754044541659661721907121840000000000,
                1105918704715895215440142199637240956944223/598236224895640697352445850600000000000, 0),
        Point3D(3662923296227402176907170887/2001416543837740000000000, 1189236919681/781250000, 0)),
 Line3D(Point3D(3662923296227402176907170887/2001416543837740000000000, 1189236919681/781250000, 0),
        Point3D(3472204942560698802701958357/2001416543837740000000000, 32496091107827/25000000000, 0))
 ]
```

[First Image](https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/12/08/RvC2NP.png)
[Second Image](https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/12/08/RvCMhp.png)

Comment: What is the criteria to separate the lines? How do we know they're similar without drawing them? Any tips?

Comment: It's not clear if the problem is showing up with the lines you have given. And is the answer below the issue or is it related to the order in which the lines are processed. If it is order, please give an ordering that works and an ordering that fails.

Comment: If the points are equal up to more than 6 digits, for any kind of real world plotting you'ld need to consider them coincident.

Answer (score 1):

Although Python has support for integers of arbitrary size, the division of two high-precision integers gives a finite precision float. So let's consider two of your integers

```
>>> n,d=1647113117371448512892615841780535357281063,737059219536588389452555455100000000000
```

And let's compare the ratios of `n/d` and `n/(d+10^20)`:

```
>>> n/d == n/(d + 10**20)
True
```

So even though the example you gave doesn't have this problem, maybe some of those in the '50-60' line case do. The simplest fix is to sympify a string of the lines you are dealing with, e.g. lines = sympify('''[Line3D(Point3D(1/2, ...))]'''). This will convert the integer ratios to Rationals of arbitrary precision and hopefully not lose precision for you when plotting.